# mac os import pymongo cause error

Tags: python-2.7, pymongo

How can I fix this problem ? tks

```
>>> import pymongo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.5.2-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/pymongo/__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.5.2-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/pymongo/connection.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.5.2-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 44, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.5.2-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/bson/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.5.2-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/bson/_cbson.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.5.2-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/bson/_cbson.py", line 4, in __bootstrap__
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 914, in resource_filename
    %s
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1601, in get_resource_filename
    """Retrieve a PEP 302 "importer" for the given path item
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1629, in _extract_resource
    from pkgutil import get_importer, ImpImporter
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 990, in get_cache_path

AttributeError: ResourceManager instance has no attribute '_warn_unsafe_extraction'
```

Comment: What `setuptools` version do you have?

Comment: @alecxe setuptools 0.8

Comment: Can you try to uninstall `pymongo`, downgrade `setuptools` to 0.7 or 0.6 and install `pymongo` again? Do you still see the error?

Comment: @alecxe thanks a lot. It was setuptools bugs.